# Nextjs dynamic routes working properly on localhost but not in deployment

Tags: next.js, routes

I am working with nextjs and facing issue regarding dynamic routes like dynamic routes file working properly on localhost but on deployed version if I refresh the browser it moves to home page of the app.

If I reload on dynamic route page it should remain on that page.

Comment: please share some code

Comment: import React from "react";

import CustomBreadcrumbs from "src/components/CustomBreadcrumbs";
import ProfileCard from "src/components/ProfileCard";
import useGetSingleDoctor from "src/hooks/useGetSingleDoctor";

const DoctorsProfile = () => {
  const doctorId = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("doctorId") as string);

  const { data } = useGetSingleDoctor(doctorId);

  return (
    <>
      <CustomBreadcrumbs />

      <ProfileCard doctor={data} />
    </>
  );
};

export default DoctorsProfile;
this is [slug].tsx file . http://localhost:3000/doctors/doctors-profile/2/ .

Comment: on local host it works fine but on deployed version if i refresh on this page it goes to /home . on all dynamic pages [slug].tsx like this i am facing this issue